# Find all functions $f:\Bbb Q\rightarrow\Bbb Q$ satisfying $f(x+y)+f(x-y)=2f(x)+2f(y)$ for all $x,y\in\Bbb Q$

Tags: functions, contest-math

> Find all functions $f:\Bbb Q\rightarrow\Bbb Q$ satisfying $f(x+y)+f(x-y)=2f(x)+2f(y)$ for all $x,y\in\Bbb Q$

I don't know how to proceed, any help would be really appreciated..

Comment: For a start: With $x=y=0$ we see that $2f(0)=4f(0)$ so $f(0)=0$. Knowing this, we can deduce that $f(0+y)+f(0-y)=2f(y)$ so $f(y)=f(-y)$.

Comment: Furthermore, with $f(y+y)+f(y-y)=4f(y)$ we see that $f(2y)=4f(y)$.

Comment: I do not know what this will tell us, but $f(2y+y)+f(2y-y)=2f(2y)+2f(y)=10f(y)$ and so $f(3y)=9f(y)$. This seems to suggest perhaps that we can show in general that $f(qy)=q^2 f(y)$, maybe.

Comment: $f(x) = A x^2$ works, constant $A.$ The rule resembles the polarization identities for quadratic forms. You know $f(0)=0,$ suppose $f(1) = B,$ what can you say about $f(2),$ then $f(3)?$

Comment: Ok, I can prove the last fact by induction, right? @String

Comment: Maybe - the only problem I see right now is how to make this relevant for $\mathbb Q$ rather than just for $\mathbb Z$. And actually, yes, I think that follows easily by induction, @Carlos :)

Comment: Oh!, so the only solutions are in the form $Ax^2$

Comment: @String If you have $f(ny)=n^2f(y)$ take $y=\frac 1n$. Then compute $f(my)=f(\frac mn)$

Comment: @MarkBennet: Yes! I just thought of that too :)

Comment: @String, it is relevant for $\mathbb Q,$ since $f(1) =f( n \cdot 1/n) = n^2 f(1/n)$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As stated in the comments, we have $x=y=0$ implies $2f(0)=4f(0)$ so $f(0)=0$. Also we must have an even function since with $x=0$ we see that $f(y)+f(-y)=2f(y)$ implying $f(y)=f(-y)$.

Now for $k\in\mathbb N$ we can prove by induction that $f(ky)=k^2f(y)$. This is clearly true for $k=1$. So if we assume this holds for $k$ and proceed to $k+1$ we see that $f(ky+y)+f(ky-y)=2k^2f(y)+2f(y)$ which rearranged yields $f((k+1)y)=2k^2f(y)+2f(y)-(k-1)^2f(y)$. Now one can simply check that $2k^2+2-(k-1)^2=(k+1)^2$ and we are done with our inductive step.

From this it follows that
$$
a^2f(y)=f(ay)=f(b\frac ab y)=b^2f(\frac{a}{b}y)
$$
so in general we have $f(qy)=q^2f(y)$ for all $q\in\mathbb Q$. Thus $f$ is entirely determined by a single function value for a non-zero input. Take for instance $A=f(1)$ and then it follows that $f(x)=f(x\cdot 1)=x^2 f(1)=Ax^2$.

Comment: Awesome, thanks!

Comment: @Carlos: Thank you! Actually in the induction I should have put two base cases since the induction hypothesis is used for both $k$ and $k-1$. But it clearly holds for $k=0$ too, so that will work :)

Comment: I noticed that, but is a minor detail

Comment: @Carlos: Yes, just like I could have mentioned that $a,b$ are integers and so on. Often times the details make it lengthy, weakening the communicative power of it ...